# Can only one partition of old hard drive been transferred to new MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

I just took the hard drive out of my MacBook pro that broke down a few days ago and put it into an enclosure. My questions; If I buy a new MacBook pro, is it possible to ONLY transfer the  `Macintosh HD partition`  from the enclosure onto the new MacBook pro, WITHOUT transferring the `Bootcamp partition`  as well?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have not look at this related to Bootcamp in a few years, but I my searches indicate this has not changed.

Apple's Migration Assistant will only look for attached Mac OS X system volumes to migrate. It will not migrate Bootcamp partitions or other data on non-boot volumes.